Outputting handwritten digits with a Neural Network
I know that you can use a neural Network to recognize handwritten digits. How would you then use that same neural network to output handwritten digits in the unique style of that network? In other words, how would you train a NN to handwrite digits?
When I look up this question I only see results on recognizing handwritten digits. I want to output them as well.
I know that they technically wouldn't be handwritten anymore but they should look like it.

You can use some generative model like GAN for this task. It works this way that there are 2 models: generator and discriminator. The discriminator learns discerning true images (from the dataset) and false (generated by generator). Generator learns to transform noise into image of digit to convince discriminator that digit is real. I did such a project some time ago. You can take a look here https://github.com/tomWitkowski/EMNIST-CONDITIONAL-GAN

But does that really use "that same neural network to output digits"? Usually , GAN would train the two networks at the same time, right? So you get two new networks.

The architecture might be slightly different as the output shape must fit the image, so it can't be exactly the same model, but the in general they can be very similar.
